# You probably need to assign the partToRotate10 variable of the Turret script in the inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

The problem is, i know what console ask(to assigned variable partToRotate10) and I did it. But console still says the message.

My brain will blown up to think what happened and Its stuck me on tutorial.

This course on youtube (minutes:18.30)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKhn2kl9_8I

[Picture of the assigned partToRotate10 in Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPr3A.jpg)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float range = 15f;
public string enemyTag="Enemy";

public Transform partToRotate10 ;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("UpdateTarget", 0f, 0.5f);
}

void UpdateTarget()
{
    GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (enemyTag);
    float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
    GameObject nearestEnemy = null;
    foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies) 
    {
        float distanceToEnemy = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, enemy.transform.position);
        if (distanceToEnemy < shortestDistance) 
        {
            shortestDistance = distanceToEnemy;
            nearestEnemy = enemy;
        }
    }

    if (nearestEnemy != null && shortestDistance <= range) {
        target = nearestEnemy.transform;
    } else 
    {
        target = null;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
    {
    if (target == null)
        return;
    Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (dir);
    Vector3 rotation = lookRotation.eulerAngles;
    partToRotate10.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0f, rotation.y, 0f);
}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range);
}
```

}

Comment: You claim you did it, why not post your code then the screenshot of the `partToRotate10` slot that shows you did it?

Comment: Please check my screenshot

Comment: Well I don't see your code. You need to post that too

Comment: thanks, and please check, I had the code

Comment: Try rebuilding your code in IDE, then refreshing scene in Unity (Cmd+R). By the way, in the code I see that you do come operations on 'target' object, yet there is nothing assigned to it in the inspector. Maybe this is causing this weird behaviour? Try it and let us know!

Comment: @target is assigned by automatically in the `UpdateTarget` function.

Comment: @Ricardo I think that you are getting different error now. On the `Console Tab`, click where it says `Clear on Play` to enable it then click play again. Ltt me know what the new error is.

Comment: Great!, I rebuild and no errors.